# array_key_exists is not working

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

array_key_exists is not working for large multidimensional array. For ex

```
$arr = array(
    '1' => 10,
    '2' => array(
        '21' => 21,
        '22' => 22,
        '23' => array(
            'test' => 100,
            '231' => 231
        ),
    ),
    '3' => 30,
    '4' => 40
);
```

array_key_exists('test',$arr) returns 'false' but it works with some simple arrays.

Comment: It's working exactly in the way it's supposed to - the array $arr does not have such a key.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

array_key_exists does NOT work recursive (as [Matti Virkkunen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948948/array-key-exists-is-not-working#comment3005438_2948948) already pointed out). Have a look at the PHP manual, there is the following [piece of code](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#81659) you can use to perform a recursive search:

```
<?php
function array_key_exists_r($needle, $haystack)
{
    $result = array_key_exists($needle, $haystack);
    if ($result) return $result;
    foreach ($haystack as $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $result = array_key_exists_r($needle, $v);
        }
        if ($result) return $result;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

array_key_exists doesn't work on multidimensionaml arrays. if you want to do so, you have to write your own function like this:

```
function array_key_exists_multi($n, $arr) {
      foreach ($arr as $key=>$val) {
        if ($n===$key) {
          return $key;
        }
        if (is_array($val)) {
          if(multi_array_key_exists($n, $val)) {
            return $key . ":" . array_key_exists_multi($n, $val);
          }
        }
      }
  return false;
}
```

this returns `false` if the key isn't found or a string containing the "location" of the key in that array (like `2:23:test`) if it's found.

Answer (score 2):

```
$test_found = false;
array_walk_recursive($arr,
                     function($v, $k) use (&$test_found)
                     {
                         $test_found |= ($k == 'test');
                     });
```

This requires PHP 5.3 or later.

Comment: indicates error at function($v, $k) use (&$test_found) and msg is 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in file.php on line 28'

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one, works on any dimension array

```
function findValByKey($arr , $keySearch){
    $out = null;
    if (is_array($arr)){
        if (array_key_exists($keySearch, $arr)){
            $out = $arr[$keySearch];
        }else{
            foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
                if ($out = self::findValByKey($value, $keySearch)){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```