# PHP : How to check value from multi arrays?

Tags: php

I have an output arrays like this..

```
array
'B5' => string 'user1' (length=5)
'B4' => string 'user1' (length=5)

array
'D3' => string 'user1' (length=5)
'D2' => string 'user1' (length=5)
'D1' => string 'user1' (length=5)

array
'A4' => string 'user1' (length=5)
'A2' => string 'user1' (length=5)

array
 'E3' => string 'user1' (length=5)
 'E2' => string 'user1' (length=5)
 'E1' => string 'user1' (length=5)
```

I would like to check if a particular item such as 'E1' exists in these arrays.
How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function.

Example:

```
$answer = array_key_exists('E1', $array_name);
```

Or, more simple:

```
$answer = isset($array_name['E1']);
```

**Sidenote:** discussion about the use of [isset() vs array_key_exists()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210935/difference-between-isset-and-array-key-exists). Worth to read if you care the performance.

Comment: array_key_exists() can be used for one dimension array... only

Comment: This will not work for the array provided in the question, this will work only for one dimension array

Comment: OP does not mention multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: see title of the question~~~

Comment: Given array is a multi dimensional array

Comment: multi-array != multi-dimensional array & i think the output is 4 arrays. Let's see how OP responses.

Answer (score 0):

This will check `array_key_exists` recursively for multi demnsional aray

```
function array_key_exists_r($needle, $haystack)
{
    $result = array_key_exists($needle, $haystack);
    if ($result) return $result;
    foreach ($haystack as $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $result = array_key_exists_r($needle, $v);
        }
        if ($result) return $result;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#82890

Comment: is that function crated by yourself? if not please mention the source!

Comment: No its from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948948/array-key-exists-is-not-working

Comment: I think they both took it from the same source .. looking at the date the php.net own is older ...