# Break is not working properly after return true;

Tags: php, foreach, return, break

The  return true; is not ending the current function loop!
This is so basic but I don't find why break is not working!

I try this piece of code:

```
function findKey($array, $keySearch) {
foreach ($array as $key => $item){
    echo "$key == $keySearch";
    if ("$key" == "$keySearch"){
        echo 'yes, it exists';
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (is_array($item))
            findKey($item, $keySearch);
    }
}
return false;
}
```

The `return true;` never break as it let it go after the `yes, it exists` is echoed!

**Solved**

The code itself from an accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420715/check-if-specific-array-key-exists-in-multidimensional-array-php/19421079#19421079) was wrong. It has been corrected. Also, below you will find the right answer.

Comment: `return` will immediately end the execution of a function and return whatever it is that you're returning.

Comment: It's what I'm use to see, but in this case it's not working!

Comment: the break statement is never executed. execution returns when it find the return satement.

Comment: It break the current foreach but still resend the function in the else statement!!

Comment: Recursive weirdness.... you're not doing anything with the return value from the recursive call to findKey()..... `if (is_array($item))
            return findKey($item, $keySearch);` perhaps?

Comment: @MarkBaker I get that piece of code from another accepted [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420715/check-if-specific-array-key-exists-in-multidimensional-array-php/19421079#19421079).  It's probably not a huge issue, but if my array became very large, it will probably affect performance!

Comment: Even though ...it's just wrong ;-)

Comment: Thank you for all your fast answers! I will try another function as this one is not that good on performance!

Comment: Try the one [that has been upvoted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19420866/4833), not the accepted one.

Comment: @VolkerK it's exactly the one I choose! Thank you

Comment: There is no `break` statement here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've jumped to a conclusion. In fact, your `return true` is *assuredly* ending the function immediately (including breaking out of the loop), but it only ends the current invocation of the function. Your solution is recursive, and has a bug in the `else` clause, whereby the result of a recursive call to `findKey` is completely ignored. As such, whatever happens inside that invocation has no effect.

You're seeing the `echo` from your outer function call.

I imagine that what you really intended to write was this:

```
function findKey($array, $keySearch)
{
   foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
      echo "$key == $keySearch";
      if ($key == $keySearch) {
         echo 'yes, it exists';
         return true;
      }
      else {
         if (is_array($item) && findKey($item, $keySearch))
            return true;
      }
   }

   return false;
}
```

I have made the same change to the original answer that you'd found.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, but it this specific case, it's causing a problem and also affecting performance. I tested both solutions, the first one took 0 sec the other one +/- 0.001 sec, in my situation it was not the best. Do you have any idea how to stop it recursively?