# How to determine whether PHP constant array key exists?

Tags: php, arrays, key, constants, exists

I want to use an array as a constant in PHP 5.6. The question is: how to check whether a key 'a' exists in the array and get the "Test2" return true as well?

My code now is like this:

```
const ARR = array(
   'a' => 'first',
   'b' => 'second'
);


$test1 = defined("ARR");
$test2 = defined("ARR['a']");

echo '<br>Test1: ';
var_dump($test1);

echo '<br>Test2: ';
var_dump($test2);
```

Result:

```
Test1: bool(true)
Test2: bool(false)
```

Comment: `$test2 = isset(ARR['a']);` (PHP7)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/array_key_exists) function

```
var_dump(array_key_exists('a', ARR));
```

defined() checks if constant is defined and it is, so you can additionaly check if constant is array with `is_array(ARR);`

**Example:**

```
<?php

const ARR = array(
   'a' => 'first',
   'b' => 'second'
);


$test1 = array_key_exists('a', ARR);
$test2 = array_key_exists('c', ARR);

echo 'Test1: ';
var_dump($test1);

echo 'Test2: ';
var_dump($test2);
```

**Output:**

```
Test1: bool(true)
Test2: bool(false)
```

**Notice:**

It will work only with PHP version >= 5.6
[Working fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/964f955fad0f7fefae9cb34fe61d1b04ea5f302b)

Comment: And what about two dimensional array?

Comment: it's the same but you need to check first dimension then second one etc. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420715/check-if-specific-array-key-exists-in-multidimensional-array-php

Answer (score 0):

In `php7+` you can use null coalescing:

```
if(self::ARR['a']??false){

}
```