# How to check whether array key is present inside multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [leadAssignType] => 3
    [ratio] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [assigned_to] => 12 
                    [ratio] => 5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [assigned_to] => 13 
                    [ratio] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

Hello all ! I am struck in one problem.  This is my array getting after form submit and I just want to check whether key assigned_to is present for at least once. If it is not present then it should show error message. How can I do that?

Comment: already answered in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420715/check-if-specific-array-key-exists-in-multidimensional-array-php

Comment: Please do a search before posting, SO has already 2 questions like that : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990868/5847906 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19421079/5847906

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple use `array_column` to get the specific column from `multidimensional array` . if the count of array is more than `zero` key `exists` otherwise key `not exists` so show the `error message` .

```
if(count(array_column($array['ratio'],'assigned_to'))>0){

  echo "key exist in the multi-dimensional array";

}else{

   echo "key not present ";   
}
```

Comment: downvoter can you please explain .then only i can correct my mistake

Comment: THIS IS CORRECT. +1. i got wrong idea, so deleted my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation  @AlivetoDie  :)

Comment: Thanks , its just exact answer for which I was looking for !!

Comment: Glad to help you :) @BhinalChauhan