# Multiple patterns within regex

Tags: php, json, regex, preg-match-all

I have a json and I need to match all "text" keys as well as the "html" keys.

For example, the json could be like below:

```
[{
"layout":12,
"text":"Lorem",
"html":"<div>Ipsum</div>"
}]
```

Or it could be like below:

```
[{
"layout":12,
"settings":{
    "text":"Lorem",
    "atts":{
        "html":"<div>Ipsum</div>"
    }
}
}]
```

The json is not always using the same structure so I have to match the keys and get their values using `preg_match_all`. I have tried the following to get the value of the "text" key:

`preg_match_all('|"text":"([^"]*)"|',$json,$match_txt,PREG_SET_ORDER);`

The above works fine for matching a single key. When it comes to matching a second key ("html" in this case) it just doesn't work. I have tried the following:

`preg_match_all('|"text|html":"([^"]*)"|',$json,$match_txt,PREG_SET_ORDER);`

Can you please give me some hints why the OR operator (text|html) doesn't work? Strangely, the above (multi-pattern) regex works fine when I test it in an [online tester](https://regex101.com/) but it doesn't work in my php files.

Comment: Why do you need to do this through regex?

Comment: @JimWright because the json doesn't always have the same layout/structure and there's no way to control that.

Comment: If it is a valid json then it can be parsed using `json_decode`

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the `text|html` in parenthesis: `(text|html)`?

Comment: have to search it if you use `json_decode`, solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420715/check-if-specific-array-key-exists-in-multidimensional-array-php

Comment: Even though its _not the same layout/structure_, if it's valid, can't you just search it like you are using regex, ie. `text` or `html` ?

Comment: You know, it's technically feasible to use regex for isolated JSON extraction. But there has to be a better reason than "regex was the first thing that came to mind".

Comment: @pchaigno Yes I have tried it with no luck.

Comment: @mario Regex is the only reliable solution in my case.

Comment: If you insist on regex, change it to `|"(?:text|html)":"([^"]*)"|`

Comment: You should find out why. Not stop at observing that it didn't work. -- To answer your question: use non-capturing grouping for local alternatives.

Comment: @sln The reason I don't want a 2nd regex for html is that I can't control the order of the values. Example: If I search for "text" and then for "html" I end up displaying the values of text and afterwards the values of html but the json may have one text, two html and the one more text. I need the order to be intact.

Comment: @sln I tired your regex and it doesn't work.

Comment: @mario I like your terminology but I was hoping for some snippet.

Comment: I see. That wasn't a concern of mine but.. Beware though, it is possible that an html <key> could be structure itself. Like `"html":{"a":"<a href="http://asdf.com">","text":"a link", "a":"</a>"}`

Comment: @otinanai Ever considered turning on error_reporting? Also, no offense, but you seem unversed with both the regex syntax and the lingo. Let me assure you, it's *not* the best approach to your perceived problem.

Comment: @mario Error reporting is always on and I don't get any errors. Of course, I'm unversed with regex and its lingo otherwise I wouldn't post my question here.

Comment: You should not be using regular expressions to parse JSON.

Comment: I tried your `I tired your regex and it doesn't work` and it works for everybody else https://regex101.com/r/6ZgrSX/1

Comment: Because, you can't say the regex doesn't work. The regex won't parse. And, that is the difference. If you don't know how to interface a regex with the language, that is another issue.

Comment: @sln It doesn't work in his environment because the parentheses are not the only issue. He also needs to change the delimiters.

Comment: @pchaigno - Who said anything about environment ? The regex works doesn't it ? What environment told him to use the pipe as a delimiter in the first place? He should know better then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/"(?:text|html)":"([^"]*)"/',$json,$match_txt,PREG_SET_ORDER);

print $match_txt[0][0]." with group 1: ".$match_txt[0][1]."\n";
print $match_txt[1][0]." with group 1: ".$match_txt[1][1]."\n";
```

returns:

```
$ php -f test.php
"text":"Lorem" with group 1: Lorem
"html":"<div>Ipsum</div>" with group 1: <div>Ipsum</div>
```

The enclosing parentheses are needed : `(?:text|html)`; I couldn't get it to work on https://regex101.com without. `?:` means the content of the parentheses will not be captured (i.e., not available in the results).

I also **replaced the pipe (`|`) delimiter** with forward slashes since you also have a pipe inside the regex. Another option is to escape the pipe inside the regex: `|"(?:text\|html)":"([^"]*)"|`.

Comment: That's well-explained now, and mostly what OP wants. (Except for capturing `html|regex` along.)

Answer (score 3):

## Fixing `text|html`

You should add `text|html` to a group, otherwise it will look for `"text` or `html"`.

```
|"(text|html)":"([^"]*)"|
```

## Delimiters

This won't currently work with your delimiters though as you use the pipe (`|`) inside of the expression. You should change your delimiters to something else, here I've used `/`.

```
/"(text|html)":"([^"]*)"/
```

If you still want to use the pipe as your delimiters, you should escape the pipe within the expression.

```
|"(text\|html)":"([^"]*)"|
```

If you don't want to manually escape it, [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) can do it for you.

```
$exp = preg_quote('"(text|html)":"([^"]*)"');
preg_match_all("|{$exp}|",$json,$match_txt,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

## Parsing JSON

Although that regex will work, it will need additional parsing and it makes more sense to use a recursive function for this.

[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will decode a JSON string into the relative data types. In the example below I've passed an additional argument `true` which means I will get an associative `array` where you would normally get an `object`.

Once `findKeyData()` is called, it will recursively call itself and work through all of the data until it finds the specified key. If not, it returns `null`.

```
function findKeyData($data, $key) {
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $data = findKeyData($v, $key);
            if (! is_null($data)) {
                return $data;
            }
        }
        if ($k == $key) {
            return $v;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

$json1 = json_decode('[{
"layout":12,
    "text":"Lorem",
    "html":"<div>Ipsum</div>"
    }]', true);
$json2 = json_decode('[{
"layout":12,
    "settings":{
    "text":"Lorem",
    "atts":{
        "html":"<div>Ipsum</div>"
    }
}
}]', true);

var_dump(findKeyData($json1, 'text')); // Lorem
var_dump(findKeyData($json1, 'html')); // <div>Ipsum</div>
var_dump(findKeyData($json2, 'text')); // Lorem
var_dump(findKeyData($json2, 'html')); // <div>Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: This answer fails to address why his regex doesn't work. He also needs to change the delimiters (`|`). Otherwise, I agree that parsing the JSON is probably a better idea in his case.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include more options on delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to use a regex to parse a valid json string:

```
array_walk_recursive(json_decode($json, true), function ($v, $k) {
    if ( in_array($k, ['text', 'html']) )
        echo "$k -> $v\n";
});
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/OKfc7)

Comment: 2¢ on BOM-prefixed JSON. (Wild guessing, since OP won't tell.)

Answer (score 0):

You use the Pipe `|` character as delimiter, I think this will break your regexp. Does it work using another delimiter like

```
preg_match_all('#"text|html":"([^"]*)"#',$json,$match_txt,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

?

Comment: this pattern returns only the `html` now.