# i couldn't get specified key using array_key_exist for json responce

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

```
$status_key ="status"

$response = {"error":false,"data":{"id":16420728,"order_id":"5000","mobile_no":"9995088810","amount":20,"balance":46.89,"status":"failure","tnx_id":"","response":"Transaction Failed"}}"


$result = json_decode($response);
```

this prints:

```
{ 
    ["error"]=> bool(false) 
    ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#24 (8) { 
        ["id"]=> int(16420728) 
        ["order_id"]=> string(4) "5000" 
        ["mobile_no"]=> string(10) "9995088810" 
        ["amount"]=> int(20) 
        ["balance"]=> float(46.89) 
        ["status"]=> string(7) "failure" 
        ["tnx_id"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["response"]=> string(18) "Transaction Failed" 
    }
}
```

now i am checking for specified key

```
var_dump(array_key_exist(status_key,result));
```

when i do `var_dump()` this function, it returns `"bool(false)"`

Comment: Variable is `$status_key`, see that `$`? Also, `status` is under `data` key.

Comment: ^ and so to `result`

Comment: `array_key_exist` needs to be `array_key_exists`

Comment: Don't post code here with syntax errors. Do your due diligence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lot of syntax mistake as well as you need to modify code a bit like below:

```
var_dump(array_key_exists($status_key,$result->data));
//- --------------------^-^-----------^-------^--^-- missing those
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/uWB7s

***For a better search approach,*** take help of this thread: [Check if specific array key exists in multidimensional array - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19421079/4248328)

```
$result = json_decode($response, true);

var_dump(findKey($result, $status_key));

function findKey($array, $keySearch)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if ($key == $keySearch) {
            return true;
        } elseif (is_array($item) && findKey($item, $keySearch)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/KaX9F

Comment: @muhammedshanid  glad to help you :)