# PHP - search for key in multidimensional array and get its values deeper from the structure

Tags: php, arrays

I am checking does specific value exist as key in array and I need to do following - if it exist to collect some data. Here is a situation:

```
$valueCode;  //(it can be EV000005, EV000010, etc.)
$temp = array_key_exists_custom($valueCode,$v); //does valueCode exist in array $v

//If it exist I need to collect it is value deeper from structure 
//For example, for EV000005 -> I want to get 'Thread holding'

if ($temp) {
$colValue; // after perfroming code, $colValue should have value  'Thread holding'
}
```

In case that I have only EV000005 in structure I will do this and get the value.

```
$colValue = $v[0][$valueCode][0][0][1];
```

But it is not solution to me because there is situation when my value will not be in `$v[0]`, f.e. when we search `EV000010` it will be in `$v[1][$valueCode][0][0][1];`. I have no idea what is the best way to get this value.

Array example:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EV000005] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => EN
                                    [1] => Thread holding
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => nl-NL
                                    [1] => Schroefdraadhouder
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [EV000010] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => EN
                                    [1] => Desoldering iron
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => nl-NL
                                    [1] => Desoldeerbout
                                )

                        )
```

Function for search in array

```
function array_key_exists_custom($needle, $haystack){
            $result = array_key_exists($needle, $haystack);
            if ($result) {
                return $result;
            }

            foreach ($haystack as $v) {
                if (is_array($v)) {
                    $result = array_key_exists_custom($needle, $v);
                }
                if ($result) {
                    return $result;
                }

            }
            return $result;
        }
```

Comment: is that part - `[0][0][1]` - always the same?

Comment: yes...it is the same. I always need to take this value.

Comment: change array_key_exists_custom to return value of key found but not boolean. It's very easy. And take `$res = array_key_exists_custom($key, $arr)[0][0][1];`

Comment: What do you mean by 'value of key found'? Value of key is that what I used for search and I am a bit confused... Question edited (added example of my function for search in array).

Comment: change `$result = array_key_exists($needle, $haystack);
    if ($result) {
        return $haystack[$needle];
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change array_key_exists_custom to return value, which found key points to, in such way:

```
$result = array_key_exists($needle, $haystack); 
if ($result) { return $haystack[$needle]; }
```

And get the result by

```
$res = array_key_exists_custom($key, $arr)[0][0][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling a bit with your description of the issue - what I infer is that you want to find data below a named key (e.g. EV000005) but you don't know where this key is in the top level array.

This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The difficulty arises because the keys you are interested in are not the the keys of the top level array. If your initial data structure was....

```
    Array (
        [EV000005] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => EN
                                [1] => Thread holding
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => nl-NL
                                [1] => Schroefdraadhouder
                            )
                    )
            )
        [EV000010] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => EN
                                [1] => Desoldering iron
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => nl-NL
                                [1] => Desoldeerbout
                            )
                    )
```

...then we wouldn't be having this conversation. You would just use

```
$colValue = $v['EV000005'][0][0][1];
```

Based on the (admittedly scarce) information you have provided, there is no reason for the first level of single element arrays, and it's making your life a lot more difficult.

Looking at the deeper data, this anti-pattern repeats, and your data should more correctly be:

```
         Array (
        [EV000005] => Array
            (
                [EN] => Thread holding
                [nl-NL] => Schroefdraadhouder
            )
        [EV000010] => Array
            (
                [EN] => Desoldering iron
                [nl-NL] => Desoldeerbout
            )
```

A further issue with your code is that you are performing data filtering operations in PHP. The data did not originate in PHP - it should be stored in a database. You should be doing your filtering and sorting in the database, not in PHP.

Assuming for now, that there is a very, **very** good reason that you can't fix the problem properly and the **only** solution is to apply your approach....

```
 function retrieve_description($item, $lang, &$arr)
 {
     foreach ($arr as $record) {
        if (is_array($record[$item])) {
           foreach ($record[$item] as $description) {
              if ($description[0]==$lang) return $description[1];
           }
           return false;
        }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Stop assigning random numbers to things which already have identifiers.

Answer (score -1):

Use function `is_array()` for each elements of array to go "deeper"