# How to find if a key exist in a matrix

Tags: php, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix[¹](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29)[²](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure)[³](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) with the following structure *(it's dynamic, may or may not contains those keys (or even more))*

```
array(
    "where" => array(
        "data_col1": "val1",
        "data_col2": "val2"
    ),
    "like" => array(
        "data_col3": "val3"
    )
);
```

What I need to do is to find if **$var_with_data_col_name** exists or not.

Using [array_key_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-key-exists.php) I can check if "where" or "like" exist, but I couldn't find a way to check inside them for a specific key.

---

PS:

**$var_with_data_col_name** would be a variable with **one** of the following strings:

```
 - data_col1
 - data_col2
 - data_col3
```

Comment: you should use recursion

Comment: If you want to check whether that variable value exists or not then you can use "array_key_exists" for that

Comment: I didn't want to use recursion, if there is function that already exist or a simple way.

Comment: @SnehalS but it will simply not work trough the dept of the array. One needs to call a testing function recursively

Comment: @Michel there's no built in function for that. You need to make your own one.

Comment: @RoyalBg I'm afraid so. The recursive solution should work for sure (it's kind the "correct" way to do it...) I'm rusty in php, and I couldn't find a function. I wasn't sure if there were any or not. And SO chat is not that great nowadays to those "simple" questions =/

Comment: @Michel: Unfortunately, given the (lack of) restrictions in the input a recursive function is what you have to use.

Comment: @Michel Maybe you should point why you don't want to use this solution? People do write their own utility/helper functions all the way in the project lifetime. Check this question and answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948948/array-key-exists-is-not-working - the marked answer points how to make a recusirve function out of array_key_exists

Comment: @RoyalBg it's a great solution, fast and correct. I just wanted to know if there were a better way. I should have used [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) to do it.

Comment: @RoyalBg this question is a dup of the one that you linked. I opened a ticked to close this as dup. Thanks again, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't search for array keys or values in multidimensional arrays directly. Walk through the array and search for it then.

```
$data_column_1_exists = false;
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(array_key_exists('data_col1', $value)
        && $key == 'where' //optionally check in specific array
    )
    {
        $data_column_1_exists = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Like [@RoyalBg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626674/how-to-find-if-a-key-exist-in-a-matrix/21626711?noredirect=1#comment32679275_21626674) and [@Jon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626674/how-to-find-if-a-key-exist-in-a-matrix/21626711?noredirect=1#comment32679710_21626674) said. Recursive is the way to go :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this -

```
function key_exists_level2($arr, $key){
    foreach($arr as $level1arr){
        if(isset($level1arr[$key])){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
//And check with
key_exists_level2($arr, $var_with_data_col_name)
```

Comment: +1 This is a "funny" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Itterate through the "main array" and use the same function for checking the keys of each "sub array"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, which gives you the key..which has your $var_with_data_col_name .

```
$data = array(
 "where" => array(
    "data_col1" => "val1",
    "data_col2" => "val2"
 ),
  "like" => array(
    "data_col3" => "val3"
 )
);

$key;
$flag = false;
$data_key = 'data_col1';

foreach($data as $our_key => $array){
if(array_key_exists($data_key,$array)){
    $key = $our_key;
    $flag = true;
}
}

if($flag){
print_r($data[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is already a function out there, more of an exercise for myself!

```
function recursive_array_key_exists($needle, array $haystack) {
    if (array_key_exists($needle, $haystack)) return true;

    foreach($haystack as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (recursive_array_key_exists($needle, $value)) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Just saw the comment linking to this answer: [array_key_exists is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948948/array-key-exists-is-not-working)

I guess mine is basically identical just less code!