# PHP array_key_exists not working

Tags: php, array-key-exists

I have a PHP array that looks like this if I **print_r($myarray)**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [description] => testdecr [link] => testlink [image_id] => 150 ) )
```

I am trying to check for a key called **image_id** by doing this...

```
if (array_key_exists("image_id",$myarray)) {
        echo 'Image_id exists';
    }
```

This is not working, anyone any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: its down a dimension see the first `[0] => Array `

Comment: Looks like your array has another array in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array\_key\_exists is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948948/array-key-exists-is-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"image_id"` key is on nested array under position `0`.
It should be:

```
...
if (array_key_exists("image_id", $myarray[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now.  Could it be modified so that it wouldn't matter how many levels there are?

Comment: @fightstarr20, welcome. Yes, it can be modified to check if `image_id` key exists on any array level, but it sounds like new input condition

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function if you use a multi-dimensional array.

```
function array_key_exists_in_multi($key, $array)
        {
            $result = array_key_exists($key, $array);
            foreach ($array as $value) {
                $result = (is_array($value)) ? array_key_exists_in_multi($key, $value) : $result;
                if ($result) return $result;
            }
            return $result;
        }
```

This simple few lines function returns true if it finds any key from the array.

**Example of the function:**

if we pass this array as a parameter in the function, we can get the expected result.

```
$arr = array(
            '1' => 100,
            '2' => array(
                '16' => 200,
                '18' => array(
                    'example' => 100,
                    '101' => 101
                ),
            ),
            '3' => 400
        );

print array_key_exists_in_multi('example', $arr); //Output is: 1
print array_key_exists_in_multi('16', $arr); //Output is: 1
print array_key_exists_in_multi('2', $arr); //Output is: 1
print array_key_exists_in_multi('20', $arr); //Output is: 0
```